# Parsear un NSData a [String: AnyObject]

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

Estoy intentando convertir este NSData

```
var elementos = [AnyObject]()
let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(elementos, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
```

la constante jsonData lleva este valor:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "paid" : false
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "paid" : false
  }
]
```

a un arreglo [String: AnyObject] para poderlo enviar como parametro en el POST, estoy usando Alamofire

```
let decoded = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]
```

pero la constante decoded siempre me queda en nil

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrias probar esto

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:elementos options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", jsonArray);
}
```